# Meaning of "main()" and "os.system" in Python 2.7.13

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am pretty new to Python (compare to everyone else) and was looking for a new things to learn about Python. So I found this simple looking program. This program is a calculator and written in much better and shorter way than I used to write. So as a new to community and this whole world of programming, I would like to ask someone to explain to me what do "main()" and "os.system" do? What is their role.
P.S. I tried to look in forums but it was a bit complex for me, can someone simplify it for me and explain it to me, I would be really greatfull!!!
Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
import os
def main():
    os.system("title Calculator Example")
    os.system("cls")
    os.system("color E")
    print "Enter the operation: "
    a = input()
    print "The answer is: ", a
    raw_input("Press Enter")
    main()

main()
```

Thank you again !!!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: os.system() is used to execute shell command, for example: os.system("echo 'hello'") will output hello in shell.

Comment: Appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 1):

In other programming languages, `main` is the first function to be called. In Python, because all code in the global scope is executed, having a main function is unnecessary. However, putting all code in a main function makes it easier to maintain and makes it so that all the code is not executed when the file is imported from somewhere else.

You can search the docs for `os.system`

Comment: So basically `main()` was the developer's function, so if I write something else like: `def four():` and define it, it will make it as a function?

Answer (score 0):

`main` is a function. A function is a block of organized, reusable code that is used to perform a single, related action. Functions provide better modularity for your application and a high degree of code reusing ([source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)). The way a function is called is by it's name, in this case, `main()`.

Another example of a function: say we had another function: `sphere_area`.

```
def sphere_area(r, radius = True):
    pi = 3.14
    if not radius:
        r /= 2.0
    return 4 * pi * r ** 2

print(sphere_area(3))
```

What `sphere_area(3)` does is it calls the function and passes in a value of 3, then returns the result of `4 * pi * r ** 2` and prints it out.

os.system is used to execute shell commands. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)